# Java Arraylist<String> calls SQL query

Tags: java, sql, arraylist

I have a method that calls a SQL query. It returns an ArrayList, so I set that to a variable temp. I am changing the old code that used ResultSet to not use it.
I am turning this:

```
if (rs.next()) {
      Password = rs.getString("EncryptedPassword");
```

into:

```
for (String x : temp) {
     Password = //something
```

I want to retrieve the Strings in the arraylist, and check if that is equal to "EncryptedPassword" 
Can you explain how the rs.getString works and how I could manipulate the new code? 
I could use an if statement instead of the foreach statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

This what the API of Java says for ResultSet and it's methods:

```
    next()
            Moves the cursor froward one row from its current position. returns boolean value

   getString(String columnLabel)
        Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this 
        ResultSet object as a String in the Java programming language.
```

So based on what we can read just there the "old code" was retrieving value of some cell by calling column name. It was iterating through each reach as method `next()` moves when cursor movement forward was possible. 
So your new code would be something like, I write pseudo code for you:

```
array_of_passwords = getData into arraylist;
for(String password: array_of_passwords){
    Password = // process data here;
}
```